API call works on rest client but not on browser
Just doing some simple Ruby on rails hello world: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#using-concerns
Super simple but for some reason I am facing an issue when reaching the url  http://localhost:3000/articles within the browser.
This is the rest client call which works
Started GET "/articles" for ::1 at 2024-09-19 21:13:06 -0700
Processing by ArticlesController#index as */*
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.3ms | GC: 0.0ms)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 300.6ms | GC: 83.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 305ms (Views: 303.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms (0 queries, 0 cached) | GC: 83.0ms)

This is the browser call which does not
Started GET "/articles" for ::1 at 2024-09-19 21:14:13 -0700
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Rendering public/406-unsupported-browser.html
  Rendered public/406-unsupported-browser.html (Duration: 0.5ms | GC: 0.0ms)
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x000000010faa86f0 /Users/joe/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/actionpack-7.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/allow_browser.rb:48 (lambda)> rendered or redirected
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 5ms (Views: 1.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms (0 queries, 0 cached) | GC: 1.8ms)

I'm wondering if the issue is ArticlesController#index as HTML when it looks like my application is returning layouts/application.html.erb
I've tried on both chrome and safari but no joy. The annoying thing is that if I save the rest client response as whatever.html and open from chrome it displays fine.

For those that have fallen to a similar fate
Commenting out the allow browser modern line in your application controller did the business
